# Why can I not call a public method in my Web Part (User Control) from an Event Receiver?

Tags: javascript, c#, sharepoint-2010, code-behind, event-receiver

I've added this Event Receiver (based on what I found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231563(v=vs.100).aspx)):

```
using System;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Security;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow;

namespace PostTravelWizard.PostTravelItemEventReceiver
{
    /// <summary>
    /// List Item Events
    /// </summary>
    public class PostTravelItemEventReceiver : SPItemEventReceiver
    {
       /// <summary>
       /// An item was added.
       /// </summary>
       public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
       {
           base.ItemAdded(properties);
           //GeneratePDF(); <= "The name 'GeneratePDF' does not exist in the current context
       }

       /// <summary>
       /// The list received a context event.
       /// </summary>
       public override void ContextEvent(SPItemEventProperties properties)
       {
           base.ContextEvent(properties);
           // TODO: What "context event" occurs here? To what event should I respond?
       }

    }
}
```

I'm hoping to, when a List is updated (from the client side/Javascript), then retrieve those values in the code-behind to generate a PDF file. I have this code in my *.ascx.cs file:

```
public partial class PostTravelWizardWebPartUserControl : UserControl
{
    . . .

    public void GeneratePDF(PostTravelData ptd)
    {
        ;//bla
    }
```

...but it's not letting my call `GeneratePDF()` from the Event Receiver - it fails with

> The name 'GeneratePDF' does not exist in the current context

Why? How can I rectify this asunto?

Comment: `GeneratePDF` is an instance method of `PostTravelWizardWebPartUserControl` class. In order to call it from `PostTravelItemEventReceiver` you have to create an instance of `PostTravelWizardWebPartUserControl` or let the method be `static`

Comment: Let which method be static - the one in the Event Receiver that calls the method in the UserControl, or the method in the UserControl?

Comment: Let the method `GeneratePDF` be `static`

Comment: `Javascript` tag should be removed

Comment: @codroipo: I get it now; I must have been in a fog this morning when I first read your comment. I added the Javascript tag because the Javascript call to populate the list is supposed to fire off the "ListUpdated" event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GeneratePDF` is an instance method of `PostTravelWizardWebPartUserControl` class. In order to call it from `PostTravelItemEventReceiver` you have to create an instance of `PostTravelWizardWebPartUserControl` or let the method(`GeneratePDF`) be `static`.

**Case 1**

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    base.ItemAdded(properties);
    new PostTravelWizardWebPartUserControl().GeneratePDF();
}
```

**Case 2**

```
public partial class PostTravelWizardWebPartUserControl : UserControl
{
    public static void GeneratePDF(PostTravelData ptd)
    {
        ;//bla
    }
}


public class PostTravelItemEventReceiver : SPItemEventReceiver
{
    base.ItemAdded(properties);
    PostTravelWizardWebPartUserControl.GeneratePDF();
}
```